# scoring R model in Python

Tags: python, r, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I am having a hard time to deploy an R model and expose it as a web service using [azuremlsdk](https://azure.github.io/azureml-sdk-for-r/articles/train-and-deploy-first-model.html) for R. The Python side of Azure machine learning appears to be more mature as Python was deemed more important by Microsoft. Anyway, I was wondering if one score an R model, persisted as .rds file, in Python. I understand R can talk to Python via reticulate. Any input from Python experts would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: sounds like you're having a rough go of it! Can you send me an email (first.last@avanade.com) and I'll try to connect you to some PMs on the Azure ML team?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to send an email using (your) first.last@avanade.com last week but it bounced. I just connected (I think) via LinkedIn